# When to use `each` and when to use the `for` loop in Groovy

Tags: loops, for-loop, groovy, closures

When do we use the `each` closure and when do we use the `for` loop in Groovy. Both effectively do the same thing.

```
groovy:000> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
===> [1, 2, 3, 4]
groovy:000> a.each {
groovy:001> println it
groovy:002> }
1
2
3
4
===> [1, 2, 3, 4]
groovy:000> for (it in a) {
groovy:001> println it
groovy:002> }
1
2
3
4
===> null
```

The `each` closure returns the list. So I can probably use it instead of the `for` loop but not vice versa, correct?

Comment: technical stuff aside, using `each` will set your mind into using the more useful functional methods like `collect`, `groupBy`, ...

Comment: see http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/using-each-versus-traditional-for-loop-td369781.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` loop is faster as You can in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009708/groovy-collections-perfomance-considerations-regarding-space-time/) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009708/groovy-collections-perfomance-considerations-regarding-space-time/24010258#24010258), but remember that *premature optimization is the root of all evil in programming* so I can't find any scenario that it really makes difference.

`each` also returns the whole, unmodified collection that it was operating on and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641211/closure-with-conditional-logging/25641438) is a particular scenario that OP found it useful.  `for` construct doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 5):

The for loop is probably somewhat faster and more memory efficient, since the each construct is syntactic sugar.  But I can't imagine a situation where it would really make a difference.

By my lights, the only significant difference is you can't terminate an each closure without throwing an exception.  You can terminate a for loop with a break.

I do think the each construct reads a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: Good points. But do you think that is all or is there more to it.

Comment: @aa8y - you could decompile a simple class using both versions and take a look at the bytecode generated to see what each does. Generally, though, the Groovy iterating constructs have a bit more overhead than simple loops so if you really need that extra performance...

Answer (score 2):

It is generally Groovier to prefer `each`, because changing the code will be easier in the future. The `each` method is related to a family of functional methods that are ubiquitous in Groovy; by contrast, the `for` loop is mired in the imperative style of Java.

As a starting example, imagine that we want `foo` to call `bar` for each item:

```
def bar = { println it }

def foo = { def a ->
    a.each { bar it }
}

foo( [1,2,3,4] )
```

Now, what if we want to call `bar` only for even numbers:

```
def bar = { println it }

def foo = { def a ->
    a.findAll{ (it % 2) == 0 }.each{ bar it }
}

foo( [1,2,3,4] )
```

What if we discover that `bar` needs the list index of the item?

```
def bar = { def item, def index -> println "${index} ${item}" }

def foo = { def a ->
    a.eachWithIndex{ def x, def i -> bar x, i }
}

foo( [1,2,3,4] )
```

Try writing these examples with the `for` loop. Sure, it can be done, but the changes seem inelegant. (Note, as mentioned in comments, you'll want to learn `collect` and other methods. `For` vs `each` is somewhat a false dichotomy.)